# Is the above definition in this book ok? ("Lecture Notes on Elementary Topology and Geometry" by I. M. Singer and J. A. Thorpe)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I am reading "Lecture Notes on Elementary Topology and Geometry" by I. M. Singer and J. A. Thorpe.

The following definition is the definition for a partial ordering in this book:

> Definition. A relation $R\subset A\times A$ is a *partial ordering* if
> (1) $(s_1,s_2)\in R$ and $(s_2,s_3)\in R\implies (s_1,s_3)\in R$ and
> (2) $(s_1,s_2)\in R$ and $(s_2,s_1)\in R\implies s_1=s_2.$

Is the above definition in this book ok?

I think the following condition is necessary for a partial ordering $R$:

> (0) $(s,s)\in R$ for any $s\in A$.

Comment: Yes, thats the reflexive definition of a POSET. (partially ordered set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that definition is not "ok", i.e. it's not equivalent to the standard definition which requires property (0) explicitly.

For example, the strict inequality '$<$' on real numbers is a partial order by your definition, but not by the standard definition. If $x<y$ and $y<z$ then $x<z$, so property (1) is satisfied. And property (2) is satisfied vacuously: There are no $x,y$ such that $x<y$ and $y<x$. But property (0) is not satisfied: $x<x$ is false.

Comment: mr_e_man, Thank you very much for your answer. I. M. Singer was a great mathematician and J. A. Thorpe is also a great mathematician. Is it possible for such great mathematicians to forget the condition (0) for a partial ordering?

Comment: (I suppose I should have said "has a property", or "satisfies a condition", not "satisfies a property".)